# Interpolating data for missing values pandas python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, interpolation, nan

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OzCUQ.png)[enter image description here][2]I am having trouble interpolating my missing values. I am using the following code to interpolate

```
df=pd.read_csv(filename, delimiter=',')
#Interpolating the nan values
df.set_index(df['Date'],inplace=True)
df2=df.interpolate(method='time')

Water=(df2['Water'])
Oil=(df2['Oil'])
Gas=(df2['Gas'])
```

Whenever I run my code I get the following message: "time-weighted interpolation only works on Series or DataFrames with a DatetimeIndex"

My Data consist of several columns with a header. The first column is named Date and all the rows look similar to this 12/31/2009. I am new to python and time series in general. Any tips will help.

[Sample of CSV file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OzCUQ.png)

Comment: What is the output of `df.dtypes`? Your "Date" column is likely strings that *look* like dates.

Comment: The issue is that it has not converted your date/time column to a date/time type.  It's still strings.

Comment: There is a parameter called `parse_dates` for the `pandas.read_csv()` function which you can use to automatically convert datetime-like columns into actual `datetime` objects during the reading in of the file, as opposed to later in your script. Try reading [the documentation!](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) There is also another parameter which allows you to set the index to a specific column, so you can actually reduce your code quite a bit just by taking advantage of the built-in functionality of `pandas.read_csv()`!

Comment: When I look at the local variables it says that Date is a dtype= dtype('0') and, the max and min say not a numeric object. So I'm assuming you are right. It thinks it is a string. I will go ahead and read the documentation. Thanks!!

Comment: In the future, try including a [sample dataset and your expected result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) when asking Pandas questions. It helps others immensely in helping to answer your question.

Comment: Thanks! It did help a lot. It is changing the nans in between the data. Just the nan values in the first row were not changing. That was confusing me. I just need to figure out how to change the ones in the first row. 
Update: The first row of nans can be changed using 
df3 = df.bfill()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, assuming the **first** column of your csv is the one with date strings:

```py
df = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=0, parse_dates=[0], infer_datetime_format=True)
df2 = df.interpolate(method='time', limit_direction='both')
```

It theoretically should 1) convert your first column into actual `datetime` objects, and 2) set the index of the dataframe to that `datetime` column, all in one step. You can optionally include the `infer_datetime_format=True` argument. If your datetime format is a standard format, it can help speed up parsing by quite a bit.

The `limit_direction='both'` should back fill any `NaN`s in the first row, but because you haven't provided a copy-paste-able sample of your data, I cannot confirm on my end.

Reading [the documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) can be incredibly helpful and can usually answer questions faster than you'll get answers from Stack Overflow!

Comment: I tried it. It did add an index to all my other columns in df. But it did not interpolate the nan values when I proceeded to try interpolate df
df2=df.interpolate(method='time')

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your csv file (as copy-paste-able formatted text) as an edit to your original post?

Comment: I added a sample. It's a long csv file. For some reason when I tried your suggestion I was not able to see the nan values change.

Comment: @JosePaz please add a **copy-paste-able** sample from your csv. The first 5 or 10 rows is fine, but it needs to be *text* that I can copy to my machine to test.

Comment: I think I understand what is happening. It fixed all my nan values except the ones in the first row. It did change all the ones in the middle.

Comment: @JosePaz you should be able to use `limit_direction='both'`. See my updated answer. Please also consider marking my solution as accepted so that your question is removed from the unanswered-queue.